# Extracting files from ZIP archive by date range

Tags: windows-xp, zip, extract

How can I extract files from ZIP archive filtering by date. I want to extract files dated between 2008-9-15 and 2008-10-1.
I have Windows XP Pro.
I would like to do it from command line. What tool/programs can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a command line to do this then you could always extract all the files and then `xcopy` the ones you want...

Something like:

```
attrib +A *.* /S
xcopy *.* temp_folder /M /S /D:10-2-2008
xcopy *.* files_you_want /M /S /D:9-15-2008
```

This sets the archive attribute on all files > copies all files from 2008-10-2 and resets their archive attribute > copies all files from 2008-9-15 which have their archive attribute set (i.e. the ones you want.

Clunky, for sure...

(Or use Windows Explorer to select the date range of course)

Comment: +1 Good idea to use xcopy after extracting thanks.